# How do I insert a view into an article based on filters that are only defined at node publish?

Tags: views

I have a website that uses data in tables. I want my copywriters to use a filtered view which will be in the node edit form to create the view they want for a particular article then somehow insert code into the page so that the data shows.

The views that are created will be different every time so this cannot be a pre-defined view as such, more a view with the filters that they decide to use at the time they publish the article.

Does anyone know how I might achieve this?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. When you talk about "views" are you referring to the views module, or just what you want things to look like?

Comment: I want the code behind the view that I see when I use filters. Let's say I create a view, then when I see the data table I want, I want to be able to serve it live in the page created. Almost like I need the view to produce me a little line of code which reflects the filters I am using at that time. But all this has to happen instantly as my content writer is creating an article. If creating an article on Brazil's top goalscorer in this year's football world cup,then he will filter TEAM: Brazil TYPE: goalscorer. This filter would then show a table with only that info in it - need to insert it.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly you have a node edit page, with a view provided by the views module with exposed filters, probably in a block in block somewhere on the page.

Your copywriter will then put some parameters into the exposed filters and get some results.

If this is a custom view that you have made then there are not going to be any pre-made modules that suit your needs so to put the content that is returned into the body your options are:

1) Copy and paste

2) Write some jQuery that runs upon clicking the view row that insert the copy into the body

[Here is some information on adding js in Drupal](https://drupal.org/node/171213).

Comment: This does not help me I'm afraid. I assumed JQuery might be able to help here in any case.

Comment: You know how to go about trying to solve the problem then. Make a start and if you get stuck on something specific then post a question on SO. At the moment what you are asking is too vague so I gave a vague answer.